# Splitting rsnapshot backup to multiple disks

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I use an RPi and an external 1 TB harddrive at my parents' place to backup my files with rsnapshot. This backup is pulled from a disk of equal size in a file server in my home which in turn consists of two directories, each one being a backup of my and my wife's workstations. I've now come to the point where the backup disks are getting full so I need to expand my storage in both my file server and the RPi. I'm thinking about splitting our backups to one disk each instead of having them share disks.

Current setup:

`server:/mnt/backup/husband/
server:/mnt/backup/wife/`

on the same drive `/dev/sdb` are being backed up to `rpi:/mnt/external/weekly.X/mnt/backup/...`

What I'd like to do is to have:

`server:/mnt/husband/
server:/mnt/wife/`

on separate drives, `/dev/sdb/` and `/dev/sdc`, being backed up to `rpi:/mnt/external_hsbd/weekly.X` and `rpi:/external_wife/weekly.X` on separate external drives.

My question is really if there is any easy way of splitting the weekly and monthly backups already made to separate drives? If I go about copying all the `rpi:/mnt/external/weekly.X/mnt/backup/husband/`to the new disk I assume I'd lose all links between `weekly.0` and all the older backups?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount `sdb` and `sdc` on your server at `/mnt/backup/husband/` and `/mnt/backup/wife`

That way you can maintain your current settings. I would not worry about names of mount points so much.

Comment: That would work for my file server but not for my remote backup, it would still write everything to the old disk. If I connect the new drive to the RPi and update the backup script it would trigger a 500 GB transfer unless I first connect the new drive to my file server and transfer everything manually (rsync or whatever) but that way I would lose all backup history...

What I'm looking for is a way of copying parts of multiple snapshots to the new drive.